# Javascript content rotator?

Tags: javascript

I’ve got the basics of a content rotator done, the only problem is it doesn’t loop itself back to the beginning and I cannot figure out why! It is a very simple javascript script:

```
window.onload = function() { setInterval("transition()", 5000); }

    function transition()
    {
        var y = document.getElementById("featured").getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
        {
            if (y[i].className == "current")
            {
                y[(i+1)].className = "current";
                y[i].className = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

It keeps stopping at the end of the list, basically I just want it to loop. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make this a little smarter by taking advantage of the wonderful language that is Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var y = document.getElementById('featured').getElementsByTagName('li');
  var ylen = y.length, index = 0;
  y[0].className = 'current';
  setInterval(function() {
    y[index].className = '';
    index = (index + 1) % ylen;
    y[index].className = 'current';
  }, 5000);
};
```

When you pre-define the list of `<li>` elements like that, the function you provide for the interval timer can reference them every time the timer fires.  The `index` variable increments up until it hits the end of the array, and then it'll be set back to zero.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
       if (y[i].className == "current") 
       { 
           if (y[i+1]]
               y[i+1].className = "current";
           else
               y[0].className = "current";
           y[i].className = ""; 
           break; 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

First time you loop you set the last elements class "current". You should put something like

```
y[0].className = "current"
```

when you reach and of the loop.